# Atmega328 watchdog, sleep and external interrupts

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino

I have a customised Arduino board that will be connected to a battery and never power reset (it needs to be very reliable and cope with code hangs).

The board will always be put to sleep when not in use. I will use 2 external interrupts on pins D2 and D3 to wake up from sleep.

A watchdog is enabled to detect program lockups whilst not sleeping. This is disabled as this shouldn't be a problem when sleeping.

Below is the code: does it look ok?

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>  
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>    // Needed to use interrupts

volatile int int0_flag;
volatile int int1_flag;

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


ISR(INT0_vect)
{
    int0_flag = TRUE;    
}


ISR(INT1_vect)
{
    int1_flag = TRUE;    
}


void sleepNow()
{   
    wdt_disable();

    byte adcsra_save = ADCSRA;
    ADCSRA = 0;  // disable ADC
    power_all_disable ();   // turn off all modules
    set_sleep_mode (SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);   // sleep mode is set here

    noInterrupts();

    sleep_enable(); 

    interrupts();
    sleep_cpu ();            // now goes to Sleep and waits for the           interrupt 
    sleep_disable ();      // precaution
    ADCSRA = adcsra_save;  // stop power reduction
    power_all_enable ();   // turn on all modules 

    //enable watchdog to check for code lockups
    wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);
}   // end of sleepNow


void setup()
{ 
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("starting...");      

    pinMode(2, INPUT);
    pinMode(3, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);

    EICRA = B00001010; // configure pin 2 and 3 for falling
    EIMSK = B00000011; // mask for INT1 and INT0

    int1_flag = FALSE;
    int0_flag = FALSE;  

    wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);

    Serial.println("ready...");  
}


void loop()
{       
    if (int0_flag == TRUE)
    {
        Serial.println("wake up from INT0");   
        int0_flag = FALSE;
    } 
    if (int1_flag == TRUE)
    {
        Serial.println("wake up from INT1");  
        int1_flag = FALSE;
    }

    Serial.println("1");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("2");
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("3");
    delay(1000);
    sleepNow();
    //while (1)
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review. I hope you receive great answers!

Comment: I don't see a `main`. What language is this?

Comment: @Mast: The Arduino uses [its own language](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage) that is based on C++.

Comment: @Edward That explains the confusion, thanks for the heads up! In that case I'm not sure whether the added [tag:C++] is fitting. Feel free to speak your mind in chat.